# Which api endpoint to use to get the users spotify playlist?

Tags: javascript, spotify, spotify-app

So there are two endpoints: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/get-a-list-of-current-users-playlists
and
https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/get-list-users-playlists

one is based on the user id and one is based on the current user but what do they mean by the current user .
Also for user id is this supposed to be based on this: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/get-current-users-profile

I can't find what they mean by the current user and the api endpoint seem to return similar things

Comment: I think "current user" means the username you used when authenticating with the API.

Comment: I don't authenticate with spotify though

Comment: Then there probably isn't a "current user".

Comment: So then I need to make a call to the other api endpoint but I need the user id but the only api endpoin that returns the user id without taking an parameters is : https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/get-current-users-profile but this is for the current user